# Can't mount a partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Thanks for the interest.

I removed my ODD and changed for a aluminium caddy with a 2.5 SSD. In other word, removed the DVD reader for the laptop in exchange it got a HDD case.

I haven't found the way to mount it, the first try was to format and since then GpartEd returns me errors.
[Suppose to be FAT32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8EtW.png)

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

returns:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc8b6fe4c
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 250069679 250067632 119.2G  b W95 FAT32**
```

But when I try to mount, I get this:

```
mano@mano-Lx:~$ sudo mount /deb/sdb /mnt
mount: special device /deb/sdb does not exist
mano@mano-Lx:~$ sudo mount /deb/sdb1 /mnt
mount: special device /deb/sdb1 does not exist**
```

It doesn't matter if the partition is Ext4, NTFS or FAT. There is no way to mount. I don't know if is because it is connected where there should be a CD player.

Let me know what is in your mind. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT according to answer**

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdb1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.

```
dmesg | tail
```

[23976.434536] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }

[23976.434541] ata3.00: error: { IDNF }

[23976.448321] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133

[23976.448363] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE

[23976.448370] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 Sense Key : Illegal Request 
[current] [descriptor]

[23976.448376] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range

[23976.448383] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e e7 c2 00 00 00 08 00

[23976.448387] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 250069504

[23976.448395] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 31258432, async page read

[23976.448421] ata3: EH complete

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `/deb` instead of `/dev`. Try

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdb1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

You should then be able to see your files in `/mnt/sdb1`, for example in Nautilus or via

```
ls -la /mnt/sdb1
```

Comment: Oh those pesky typos